# What is thread (java, android)?

Tags: android, multithreading

Can someone give me a "simple" definition about Thread in android. I read the definition on the Android Site but It's really hard for me to imagine!

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What can't you imagine?

Comment: A thread on Android is the same as a thread in any other platform/programming language. Perhaps Wikipedia can get you started on threads.

Comment: I read a book name "Java for Dummies". The definition was describe easy to understand (but has not Thread).

Comment: Don't confuse the Java language with the Java libraries - they are separate!

Comment: That an example for you to understand my question easily. I learn Android so I need to know the language too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sound like you could use a semi-real-world example.  Google revealed this [handy blog post](http://saeedsiam.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-look-into-android-thread.html).

For a general reference (as mikem suggested) see Wikipedia: [Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)).  Threads are pretty much the same in every framework.

Answer (score 3):

A Thread can best be imagined by picturing a thread (lolz).
Lets say you have made a program to show some text on the screen.
Now when you run the program all the code execution happens on one imaginary line (thread).

Now you extend your program to place a new line of text on the screen every 10 seconds.
You have few options:

1: Make a while loop and inside the loop show the text and make the program stop (sleep) execution for 10 seconds.
Nasty side effect is that you cannot interact with your program at all for the duration of every 10 seconds (because the thread is sleeping).
This is not what you want :)

2: Make a new thread with a while loop that shows the text on the screen and makes the thread sleep every 10 seconds. Now because this second thread is sleeping for 10 seconds you can still interact with your first main thread :)

Tutorial:
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

Good luck, may the source be with you.

Answer (score 0):

The thread models for Android is a bit different, in the way that they recommend using an AsyncTask. Read AsyncTask documentation. It's like a thread.

Comment: It's common to see these sorts of features as threads *can* be difficult to use properly - .Net has its BackGroundWorker which is essentially a wrapper class for a thread which abstracts away some of the details of thread management.  That being said, simplifying threads this way also makes it harder to do some more advanced things:  AsyncTask can only be created on the main UI thread, and can only be run once.  It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.